# Is there an opcode in PHP VM that lets you stack allocate?

Tags: php-internals

Title. Since you can enable escape analysis, there should also be an opcode that uses stack allocation instead of heap, right? Or how would that work?

Comment: I don't know about the PHP VM, but escape analysis does not require that the entire object gets stack allocated. The compiler could simply output bytecode that doesn't create the entire object at all, instead only directly allocating the members that are actually used

Comment: @UnholySheep That is true, I guess. Maybe someone could shed some light on that as well. :)